# Shifted sum of reciprocals of primes: $\sum \limits_{\forall p \in primes}\frac{1}{p+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I know that the sum:

$\sum \limits_{\forall p \in primes}\frac{1}{p}$ diverges.

I was wondering if:

$\sum \limits_{\forall p \in primes}\frac{1}{p+1}$ diverges as well.

And if there is a formula for the partial sum of primes up to an upperbound $n$.

My guess is that it does but I'm not quite sure what the quick way to show it is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: limit comparison test.

Comment: The other solutions (and hints) are fine but you could also just note that $p_n+1≤p_{n+1}$ so you  can directly compare the two.  (Note:  here $p_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ prime.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime. Then these two series diverge:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/p_n
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/p_{n+1}
$$
Since $p_{n+1} \geq p_n + 1$, we conclude that the series you described is divergent as well.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\frac{1}{p+1} \ge \frac{1}{2p}.
$$
For partial sum of reciprocals of primes asymptotic is well known:
$$
\sum_{p< n} \frac{1}{p} = \log \log n + M_n,
$$
where $\lim_{n\to \infty}M_n = M$ is [Meissel–Mertens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant) constant.

Comment: The last equation is not correct. The $M$ should be replaced by $M_n$  where  $\lim_{n\to \infty}M_n=M. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks, corrected.